# Vuetify dialog with multiple activators

Tags: vue.js, dialog, vuetify.js

I have a dialog made in vuetify and want it to have multiple possible buttons, which activate it. The buttons are different from each other and in several different components. So I cannot just import the dialog component to the locations, because then the buttons are all same, as they are defined in the dialog:

```
<v-dialog>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <v-btn
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on"
    >
      Activate
    </v-btn>
  </template>

  <v-card>
    My Content
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

Is there a way, without just duplicating the component file to reach my goal?

Comment: The question is unclear because it sounds like just adding another button to the activator slot would do what you want

Comment: @shob Oh you are right, I added the pretty essential missing information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a global modal component to place in *App.vue*, and trigger it with `v-model` instead of activators.  The `v-model` uses a global state (like from Vuex, etc.) which you can toggle from anywhere:

*Modal*

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="$store.state.isModal">
    <v-card>
      My Content
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

Then you can toggle that state in some other component:

```html
<v-btn @click="$store.dispatch('showModal')">SHOW</v-btn>
```

[Here's a demo](https://codepen.io/sh0ber/pen/xxRajEo?editors=1010) using [`Vue.prototype`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Base-Example) and [`Vue.observable`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) instead of Vuex for the global state